# Is it possible to change the read-only/read-write status of a docker mount at runtime?

Tags: docker

I have a dockerized application that uses the filesystem to store lots of state. The application code is contained in the docker image

I am considering a update strategy which involves sharing the volume between two containers, but making sure that at most one container at a time can write to that filesystem.

The workflow would be:

- start container A with /data mounted rw
- start container B with /data mounted ro, and a newer version of the application
- stop serving requests to container A
- for container A, make the /data mount read-only
- for container B, make the /data mount read-write
- start serving requests to container B

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can re-mount your volume from inside the container, in the `rw` mode, like that:

```
mount -o remount,rw /mnt/data
```

The catch is that mount syscall is not allowed inside the Docker containers by default so that you would have to run it in a privileged mode:

```
docker run --privileged ...
```

or enable the [SYS_ADMIN](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#runtime-privilege-and-linux-capabilities) capability

> SYS_ADMIN Perform a range of system administration operations.

```
docker run --cap-add=SYS_ADMIN --security-opt apparmor:unconfined
```

(note that I have had to also add --security-opt apparmor:unconfined, to make this work on Ubuntu).

Also, remounting the `rw` volume back to `ro` might be tricky, as some process(es) might have already opened some files inside it for writing , in which case the `remount` will fail with `is busy` error message.

But my guess is that you can just restart the container instead (as it would be the one running an old version of the app).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Indeed, mapping rw → ro will most likely not work.

Comment: I have created a container using - 
docker run -v /var/www/html/docker-volume/:/docker-volume/:ro -p 8080:80 --name test b05752a629b5
Can you please help me to make it rw? I am not sure how to use the command that you wrote.

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly what the OP requested, but I've had a similar question where i needed to get data OUT of the running container, but had mounted RW.

Other ways to extract the data would have taken too long.

My approach ? Stash the container as an image and start a new container *from that Image* with a mount as RW :D

Initial container start:

```
docker run  -p 80:8080 --mount type=bind,source="C:\data-folder-local\",target=/data-folder-container-ro,readonly -d imageName:imageTag
```

Making an image from the container. You can stop this container before/after if you want.

```
docker commit -a "mud" -m "Damn, mount should be rw, stashing a snapshot to reuse." CONTAINER_ID_HERE snapshotImageName:snapshotImageTag
```

where **CONTAINER_ID_HERE** i got from the output of `docker ps` (https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/ps/)

Start a *new container* from the image made, but this time mount with write rights!

```
docker run  -p 80:8080 --mount type=bind,source="C:\data-folder-local\",target=/data-folder-container-rw -d snapshotImageName:snapshotImageTag
```

write out files to the mount folder (on local system) from within your container :D

Hope that helps somebody.